# Include statement not working in PHP/Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have two files, the first one being in the main directory, console_output.php:

```
<?php
class console_output
{
  function write_to_logfile($text) {
    file_put_contents("log.txt", $text);
  }
}
?>
```

and the second one in a subdirectory, xController.php

```
<?php 
...import stuff...
include ("../console_output.php");

class xController extends Controller{
  ...do_stuff..

  function doMoreStuff(){
  ...

    $console_output = new console_output();
    $console_output->write_to_logfile("did Stuff");
  }
}
?>
```

This is all in Yii2 framework, in case that matters. I have tried with apps/console_output.php and ../console_output.php, but it fails either way.
When I use apps/console_output.php, the error is

> include(app/console_output.php) [https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php'>function.include.php]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

The error is shown right at the include statement.

Using ../console_output.php in the include statement gives me an error at

```
$console_output->write_to_logfile("did Stuff");
```

with the message

> Class 'app\controllers\console_output' not found

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Can you help me out please?

Comment: You can use alias on yii2 to set the path for your files. [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases) [list](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app)

Answer (score 1):

Yii(2) offers multiple shortcuts to various paths. The most commonly used one is

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl
```

So You can include your php file like:

```
$url = Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl.'/../console_output.php';
include $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You relative path Def nation is wrong. You are using .. that mean you moving a director up from current script. You need to use "subdirectory/script.php"

Comment: but the include statement is in the file in the subdirectory, so if I want to call the function from the file in the main directory I have to move out of the subdir.

Comment: Where is log.txt located? Is it in same directory as console_output.php

Comment: yes. console_output and log.txt are together, xController in the subdirectory.